# Overriding color of Typography changes color of AlertTitle?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

By default, the `<AlertTitle>` color is independent from the `Typography` color.

For example, I have the following component,

```
<Stack>
  <Typography variant="h1">H2</Typography>
  <Alert severity="success">
    <AlertTitle>
      <strong>TITLE</strong>
    </AlertTitle>
  </Alert>
</Stack>
```

and the `<AlertTitle>` color is `rgb(30, 70, 32)` and the `Typography` is black.

[image]

However, when I override the color of `Typography` globally in the theme like this,

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTypography: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          // this will change the color of AlertTitle too
          color: "red",
        },
      },
    },
  }
});
```

It changes the color of `AlertTitle` as well:

[image]

This looks like an issue to me. The color of `AlertTitle` should not be affected by the color of `Typography`, which is the default or am I missing something here?

Comment: `AlertTitle` is one of many MUI components that [leverage Typography](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.12.2/packages/mui-material/src/AlertTitle/AlertTitle.js#L20) internally.

Comment: By the default, the color of `Typography` (black) does not change the color of `AlertTitle` (`rgb(30, 70, 32)`). Shouldn't this behavor remains the same when I change orride the color of `Typography` to red? The color of `AlertTitle` should remain unchange.

Comment: Black is not the default color for `Typography`. By default, `Typography` doesn't specify any `color` CSS -- the text just inherits the color specified for ancestor elements. But you are causing all `Typography` elements to now specify `color` CSS.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Now I see your points, I appreciate your explanation. Looks like it is not a good idea to override the color of `Typography` globally.